# What is the most efficient way (both time and memory) to add a new row to a matrix in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix, memory, rbind

I have a matrix and I need dynamically add rows to this matrix (the size is not known). The best practice is to use `rbind`, i.e.

`my_matrix <- matrix(NA, 2, 2)
my_matrix <- rbind(my_matrix, c(1, 2))`

However, calling a function will create a new matrix `rbind(my_matrix, c(1, 2))` and only then assign it to `my_matrix`. Furthermore, calling a function will cost some time.

Is there any way to avoid creating a new object / calling a function?

Comment: How the rows are generated one by one? Eventually you can use `sapply()`. In the current state your question about opinion ("most efficient").

Comment: in short: no. the best solution will depend on your use case.

Comment: I believe `my_matrix[c(6,7)] <- c(1,2)` would modify in place, but it would be the equivalent of adding a column, not a row, and then losing the dimension attribute. So in your case as I suppose you want to iterate adding rows, you'd have to transpose first, then add columns, then when it's done format and transpose back.

Comment: Actually if you just preallocate all the space, what you should do anyway, you can assign rows or columns alike.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper 1) it is actually a nice solution, thanks 2) that's the thing: I don't know apriori the number of rows.

Comment: Could you set an upper boundary ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper nope. I need this for simulation of a stochastic process until a certain stopping time.

Comment: Then Maybe build a one element list containing a preallocated matrix of 100 million rows (or more or less depending on your system), then fill it up, keeping track of the number of rows, when there's no room in the matrix for the next batch, trim your current matrix and start another one. In the end concatenate all of them. There'll be copies, but 100M times less. I don't know the most efficient way to rbind a list of matrices, but hopefully there won't be so many of them and `do.call(rbind,your_list)` will work ok.

Comment: Does it make sense to you? I can draft it as an answer if it helps

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Absolutely. Binding matrices shouldn't be a big issue then. Thanks! However, dropping dim attribute of a matrix and treating as a vector seems to me a bit more elegant. Right now I stick to it.

Comment: Elegant as in shorter code and without the awkward split, but if you don't preallocate I believe it will be slower. I would be interested to know what you've chosen when you're done and how faster than original solution it is.